# Correct way to add frameworks to an iOS project to be included in subversion

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, svn, repository

I need to add a framework to my iOS 7 project. The problem begins when I try to commit the addition of the framework to an SVN repository. After being updated in another host, the framework location appears to be relative to my computer's location of the .framework file, causing the project to be impossible to build.

Since I will be needing to add more frameworks in my project, how can I add them safely so that other people in my work group can use them and more importantly be able to build the project?

Thanks for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options here:

1- When you drag the new framework to your project, check the box that says copy the files into my project if needed.

2 - Manually, copy the framework into your project directory, then drag it to your project, and uncheck the copy if needed box.

Hope this works for you. If not, let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think that it is the correct way to add the framework to subversion, but I still have issues running my code using the Facebook framework, so I switched to the Social framweork that is included in iOS 7 framework library.